# What are the requirements for HTA files?

Tags: windows, dependencies, browser, hta

They seem to open in an internet explorer type window, does anyone know:

- How long have HTA files been around? Have they been around since Windows 98?
- Do they rely on Internet Explorer being installed, and/or a certain version of it?
- If you choose another browser on the browser selection screen update for Windows 7, will HTA files still work?
- Do HTA files open on other browsers?
- Are HTA files windows-only?

There is a huge lack of documentation on google about HTA files, so it's tricky to work out. I need to present the client with a list of minimum requirements to ensure our HTA content CD will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HTA Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28VS.85%29.aspx)

- Yes
- IE5+
- Yes, .HTA is associated with IE
- No
- Yes

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia's [HTML Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) is another good reference. HTA files are hosted in MSHTA just like HTML files are hosted in web browsers. Both MSHTA and IE share the same web browser components.

- They've been around since 1999.
- If IE is not installed, then, the web browser components used in MSHTA are unavailable
- Even if you choose another browser, HTA files still require MSHTA to run.
- HTA files do not run in a browser, they run inside MSHTA.
- HTA files run inside MSHTA which only exists on Microsoft Windows.